# Pull-back of 1-form

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms, pullback

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ be the parameterization $f(\theta) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$. If $\alpha$ is a 1-form on $\mathbb{S}^1$, prove that $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \alpha = \int_0^{2\pi} f^*\alpha.$$ I know $$f^*\alpha(\theta) = (df_\theta)^*\alpha(f(\theta)),$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Proving the integral equation

Comment: How did you define the integral of a 1-form on $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: I believe $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \alpha = \int_0^{2\pi} \alpha(f'(\theta))\,d\theta$

Comment: So you are identifying $\mathbb{S}^1$ with its canonical embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and implicitly lifting $\alpha$ to a one-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Then does your identity not follow from just pushing symbols around and rearranging stuff?